# VBA function - argument is not optional

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function:

```
Function EntryInTable(stringToBeFound As String, arr1 As Variant) As Integer

EntryInTable = 0
Rem default return value if value not found in array
      For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
      If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr1(i, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            EntryInTable = EntryInTable + 1
            Exit For
      End If
Next i

End Function
```

The array contains the following range data:

```
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Set r3 = Sheets("Konten Tabelle").Range("Tabelle4[[Konto]:[Gruppe]]")
  i = r3.Rows.Count
  Rem Datenfeld für die Konten-Tabelle
  ReDim arr(1 To i, 1 To 2)
  For j = 1 To i
        arr(j, 1) = r3.Cells(j, 1)
        arr(j, 2) = r3.Cells(j, 2)
  Next
```

the function itself seems to work fine, however upon calling I receive the error argument is not optional:

```
Call EntryInTable(Target.Value, arr)
If EntryInTable > 0 Then
      Debug.Print EntryInTable
End If
```

I have searched in many forums, including this without success. Thanks to anyone for answers.

Comment: what does arr contain?

Comment: sorry, just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines...

```
If EntryInTable > 0 Then
      Debug.Print EntryInTable
```

Because the function EntryInTable requires two parameters and you are not passing any.

Instead declare an integer variable in your calling sub and so that the function is called only once otherwise even if you pass the parameters correctly the function will be called three times with these lines...

1. `Call EntryInTable(Target.Value, arr)`
2. `If EntryInTable > 0 Then`
3. `Debug.Print EntryInTable`

You may try something like this...

```
Dim cnt As Integer
cnt = EntryInTable(Target.Value, arr)
If cnt > 0 Then
      Debug.Print cnt
End If
```

Comment: the function also has an error i guess, it does no return any value

Comment: Well I don't think so. Did you try the function and noticed an issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Call is unnecessary here. The function does not automatically come back with an assigned value to the variable. 
When you typed this -`If EntryInTable > 0`, you were invoking the function again with no arguments.

You need to assign it to another variable, like:

```
Dim entryPoint as Long
entryPoint = EntryInTable(Target.Value, arr)
If EntryInTable > 0 Then
    Debug.Print EntryInTable
End If
```

Also you must define EntryInTable to return a Long:

```
Function EntryInTable(stringToBeFound As String, arr1 As Variant) As Long
```

Integer is unnecessary in VBA. No need to save memory. Your worksheet data will overflow in bigger datasets. Basically Integer is to be avoided - as the cons outweigh the pros.